# How to get sum of specific number of nested objects in an array sorted by date with aggregation pipeline, MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I need to get the sum of the "points" of the 3 most recent entries/objects under members array based on date. So, the total points should be **3000**. (Person B 500, Person C 1000, and Person D 1500).

How do I do that with my current aggregation pipeline? Do I use slice or something?

**Here's the document**

```
[{
  "_id": { "$oid": "00001" },
  "leaderId": 001,
  "leader": "Josh",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Person A",
      "points": 500,
      "date": 2023-05-30T18:00:00.000+00:00
    },
    {
      "name": "Person B",
      "points": 500,
      "date": 2023-05-30T19:10:00.000+00:00
    },
    {
      "name": "Person C",
      "points": 1000,
      "date": 2023-05-30T19:20:00.000+00:00
    },
    {
      "name": "Person D",
      "points": 1500,
      "date": 2023-05-30T19:30:00.000+00:00
    }]
  }]
```

Here's my aggregation pipeline that returns **3500** because it gets the sum of points from all objects under members array.

```
db.users.aggregate([{ $match: { leader: "Josh" } },
{$unwind: "$members"},
{$sort: {"members.date": -1}},
{$group: {_id: "$leaderId", latestThreePoints: {$sum: "$members.points"}}}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your current work, you just need an extra `$limit` stage after the `$sort`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      leader: "Josh"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$members"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "members.date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 3
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$leaderId",
      latestThreePoints: {
        $sum: "$members.points"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5lqdNIagFeC)

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. When I was troubleshooting I placed the limit at the end of group stage.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@ray's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76359488/20042973) that you can achieve your desired result from the starting pipeline by adding a `$limit` stage.

That said, it seems as if the `_id` field is related `leaderId` field. If so, that means that the `$unwind` -> processing -> `$group` on `leaderId` approach being used is an antipattern as it unnecessarily introduces a blocking stage.

Instead, consider processing the documents in place. You mentioned `$slice` which seems like the appropriate solution to me. If we know that the `members` array is always in ascending order, then the following should compute what you want:

```
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: "$leaderId",
      "latestThreePoints": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$slice": [
              "$members",
              -3
            ]
          },
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            $sum: [
              "$$this.points",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ly6HKZk0tTb).

If the array is *not* always sorted, but you are on version 6.0 or higher, then you can use [the `$sortArray` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/). The stage would look as follows:

```
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: "$leaderId",
      "latestThreePoints": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$slice": [
              {
                $sortArray: {
                  input: "$members",
                  sortBy: {
                    date: -1
                  }
                }
              },
              3
            ]
          },
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            $sum: [
              "$$this.points",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sde9prt6PZW).

Also of note, you can use `$addFields` instead of `$project` if you would like to add this new field to the existing fields in the document as opposed to removing all of the others.

Comment: Thanks! I did look up sortarray and slice earlier. I understand it now.